# Windows 10 loop through several folders and move specific data from them

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a folder (let's call it *mainFolder*) which holds hundreds of more folders inside. In each of these hundreds of folders I have two png images and a text file. I want to move (or copy) all the text files into a folder (let's call this *targetFolder*). How can I do this in Powershell or Batch?

Comment: can you share what you've already attempted?

Comment: Nothing yet, I have no clue where to start. But maybe something like this: 

    `for /R %a in (.) do copy "%a" D:\New`


But that code does not loop through folders in folder.

Comment: @nh3, that edit makes the question unclear. If there is any chance that the `targetFolder` will be in the `mainFolder`, then rollback your edit and ask that the respondees incorporate that scenario into their answers!

Comment: There @Compo. I have clarified the question for you.

Comment: @EBGreen, technically you've clarified nothing, you've merely taken it upon yourself to change the OP's question so that the solutions take precedence over the goal!

Comment: @Compo The OP stated that the solution was correct. The OP has stated that the solutions ***do not*** need to include the requirement that target resides in source. You clearly feel that you know the clear way to write this question so feel free to do so. That is the way that stackoverflow works.

Comment: @EBGreen, the OP wrote, 'I want to move (or copy) all the text files into a folder (let's call this *targetFolder*) **which will be in the \*mainFolder\***'. They later changed it to read, '**which can be somewhere else (not in the \*mainFolder\* necessarily)**'. The OP's edit did not, state that solutions did not need to include the requirement, there was still a possibility that the directory could still exist within mainFolder, removing that suggestion prevents others from potentially providing a more robust solution. _Changing a question to match one or more answers is not good practice_.

Comment: @Compo The OP did state in a comment that the edge did not need to be handled. Again, if you feel that you know the proper way for the question to be written, then fix it. I did not rewrite the question for the purpose of matching the answer. I rewrote the question to remove extraneous requirements that the OP stated in a comment were not required. Feel free to ask about the edit on Meta if you feel I am wrong or even edit the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move all items from source (including subfolders) to the destination.

This should do it:

```
$Source = "C:\Source"
$Destination = "C:\Destation"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $Destination
```

You can add -Whatif to the end of the Get-ChildItem (after $Destination) in order to test it before execution

If you want to copy only you can replace the Get-ChildItem line with :

```
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Include "*.txt" -Destination $Destination
```

Comment: If `targetFolder` will be in the `mainFolder` as in the question, would it not be prudent to exclude `targetFolder` from the recursion?

Comment: Yes, true. That's not necessary to have the destination folder **inside** the mainFolder - so this code worked like a charm.

Comment: @nh3, you should either remove that requirement from your question or request that the answer above actually better reflects what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, as an example if you want to copy all `txt` files from the source, recursively in all sub directories:

```
for /R "c:\source folder" %%f in (*.txt) do copy "%%f" "c:\destination folder\"
```

to actually move the files, simply use the command instead of copy, perhaps consider the `/Y`

If however your `destination folder` were to be inside of your `source folder` you could simply ignore it.

```
for /R "c:\source folder" %%f in (*.txt) do (
if not "%~dpf"=="c:\source folder\" copy "%%f" "c:\destination folder\"
)
```

Comment: Noting within the question that `targetFolder` will be in the `mainFolder` will there be issues picking up `destination folder` inside `source folder` in your example code?

Comment: @compo, I don't quite get the question? I am doing a recursive search for `*.txt` from within the source folder as the root directory and then copy each of the `txt` files to the destination folder.

Comment: @Compo ok wait, I get what you are saying. He however never mentions target will be in the source dir, so I doubt that is the case.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard there was a potential edge case in the question where the Target folder might have been a subfolder of the source folder. The OP has confirmed that in this case that edge case does not exist. Compo was trying to get the answers to include this edge case.

Comment: The question as initially written did say that target could be located in source.

Comment: Prior to the, _now unclear edit by the OP_, their `targetFolder`, _i.e. your `destination folder`_, was stated to be a subfolder of `targetFolder`, _i.e. your `source folder`_. Your example clearly shows them as independent of each other and did not therefore meet the criteria of the question at its time of posting.

Comment: @EBGreen yes, I see the edit history now, I however answered after edited, but I will include edge case in my example as a _nice to know_

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, the OP edited that particuar part of their question after I had raised it in a comment, and around ten minutes after your your most recent edit.

Comment: @Compo What would you like me to do? Delete the answer?

Comment: It is a moot issue. The OP has stated that the edge case was not an issue and the question is now clear regarding that.

Comment: @Compo edited my answer to cater for the pre-edited version.

Comment: Sorry for the fuss. I didn't realize in the beginning that having the target folder inside the source folder is both unnecessary but also problematic.